# How to determine equaivalent groupings (recursively) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of products identified by their SKUs. To simplify it, I just name them as A, B, C, D,... here. Each of these SKUs has been assigned by default an already existing `GroupID`, for simplicity I just number them as 1, 2, 3,... here.

The same `GroupID` would mean "These SKUs are equivalent, so it is ok to use/buy either one of them, as it makes no difference".

The problem is, some SKUs show up more than once as they come from a different buying source, but as they come from a different source, they have a different grouping.

The goal is therefore to consolidate the grouping and make sure they have the same groupings.

I already apologize if my illustration may not be super pretty, but I'm trying. Here's a small data table sample on how the raw data looks like (first line is the column names):

```
    Source      SKU  GroupID
    Seller1      A      1
    Seller1      B      1
    Seller1      C      1
    Seller2      B      2
    Seller2      D      2
    Seller2      E      2
    Seller3      A      3
    Seller3      B      3
    Seller4      F      4
    Seller4      G      4
    Seller4      H      4
```

The result should be like:

```
    Source      SKU  GroupID
    Seller1      A      1
    Seller1      B      1
    Seller1      C      1
    Seller2      B      1
    Seller2      D      1
    Seller2      E      1
    Seller3      A      1
    Seller3      B      1
    Seller4      F      4
    Seller4      G      4
    Seller4      H      4
```

Basically, if `Any SKU in GroupID X is a subset of GroupID Y, then GroupID Y = GroupID X`. But that should be applied on all GroupIDs, so it appears to be recursive.

I wish I could show the code that I tried already and I tried already for a few days, but I literally only managed to produce garbage.

In C# I'd know how to deal with this, but I can't seem to wrap my head around SQL as I am not that experienced and unfortunately I would need this in SQL.

I would be thankful for any kind of help, even if it's just a hint or direction you guys would suggest I should try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick I am using the latest 8.0 Community Edition version

Comment: Seller2 doesn't have any subset, why its returning groupID 1?

Comment: @EdBangga B is a subset of GroupID 1

Comment: It took me some time to go through @GordonLinoff 's code and understand it, but I appreciate everyone's input here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a correspondence between groups, which you can calculate with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tt as (
      select distinct t1.groupid as groupid1, t2.groupid as groupid2
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.sku = t2.sku 
     ),
     cte as (
      select tt.groupid1, tt.groupid2, concat_ws(',', tt.groupid1, tt.groupid2) as visited 
      from tt
      union all
      select cte.groupid1, tt.groupid2, concat_ws(',', visited, tt.groupid2)
      from cte join
           tt
           on cte.groupid2 = tt.groupid1
      where find_in_set(tt.groupid2, cte.visited) = 0
     )
select groupid1, min(groupid2) as overall_group
from cte
group by groupid1;
```

You can then join this back to the original table to get the "overall group":

```
with recursive tt as (
      select distinct t1.groupid as groupid1, t2.groupid as groupid2
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.sku = t2.sku 
     ),
     cte as (
      select tt.groupid1, tt.groupid2, concat_ws(',', tt.groupid1, tt.groupid2) as visited 
      from tt
      union all
      select cte.groupid1, tt.groupid2, concat_ws(',', visited, tt.groupid2)
      from cte join
           tt
           on cte.groupid2 = tt.groupid1
      where find_in_set(tt.groupid2, cte.visited) = 0
     )
select t.*, g.overall_group
from t join
     (select groupid1, min(groupid2) as overall_group
      from cte
      group by groupid1
     ) g
     on t.groupid = g.groupid1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebcad80448b31514fecba1935d9cc225) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  Your sample data is rather "complete" so you don't need a recursive CTE for that particular data.  However, I am guessing that your real groups have a bit less overlap in which case recursion is necessary.

Comment: You're right, the real groups are less overlapping, so recursion is necessary. Thanks a lot, your answer was very helpful and insightful :)

Answer (score 0):

First is to get all those sellers with subsets based on count. then filter using Group By

```
select table1.Source, SKU, case when table1.Source = t6.Source and t6.cnt > 1 then 1 else 2 end as GroupID
from table1
left join
  (select t5.Source, count(t5.cnt) as cnt from (
    select distinct t4.Source, t4.cnt from (
      select t3.Source, count(t3.SKU) as cnt from (
        select t1.Source, t1.SKU from table1 t1
        left join table1 t2 on t2.SKU = t1.SKU ) t3
      group by t3.Source, t3.SKU
      order by t3.Source) t4) as t5
   group by t5.Source) t6 on t6.Source = table1.Source
```